# prolog list out every possible path of the recursion

Tags: recursion, path, prolog

I would like to list out every possible path

```
country(england,france). 
country(france,bulgaria).
country(bulgaria,germany).
country(england,bulgaria).
country(germany,italy).
edit: additional to

country(germany,italy).
country(england,italy).
country(england,greece).
country(greece,france).

connectto(X, Y) :-
country(X, Y).
```

?-op(150,xfy,to).

X to Y:-get_waypoints(X,Y,Waypoints),write(Waypoints),fail.

```
get_waypoints(Start, End, [Waypoint|Result]) :-
   country(Start, End),
   !;country(Start, Waypoint),
   get_waypoints(Waypoint, End, Result).
```

otherwise from the original code the 
system will give out

```
   | ?- england to italy.
   []no
```

from the code you mention.

now the problem comes into

```
    | ?- england to italy.
    [_31242|_31243][france,bulgaria,germany,_31332|_31333]   
    [bulgaria,germany,_31422|_31423]
    [greece,france,bulgaria,germany,_31602|_31603]no
```

although it shows out all possible route.

Any solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask if you need explanation :

```
country(bulgaria,germany).
country(england,bulgaria).
country(england,france). 
country(england,greece).
country(england,italy).
country(france,bulgaria).
country(greece,france).
country(germany,italy).

:- op(150, xfy, to).

X to Y :-
    findall(Waypoint, get_waypoints(X,Y,Waypoint), Waypoints),
    write(Waypoints).

get_waypoints(Start, End, []) :- 
    country(Start, End).
get_waypoints(Start, End, [Waypoint|Result]) :-
    country(Start, Waypoint),
    get_waypoints(Waypoint, End, Result).
```

Use is :

```
?- england to italy.
```

Here, I updated my code to match your expectations.

Comment: yes, but i've mention this only giving 1 solution. I need mutiple different data. I've tried the fail and return but it doesnt work

Comment: it does not give only 1 solution, you certainly forgot to add the first clause on top of the second one. Do you confirm that when you copy paste my code and test it it returns only one solution ? And which implementation of prolog are you using ?

Comment: im using lpa win prolog. and it really did give only 1 solution. Also, using fail giving me multiple paths but some aint correct. sorry i forgot to mention that it should be (adam,jim) and list out matt and frank.

Comment: if you don't use a free variable as second parameter, you already bind the result, so calling your predicate will only tell you if jim is an ancestor or not.  You need to call your predicate with a free variable as second argument. Like ?- ancestor(adam, X).

Comment: yes that what i was intent but for it similar to saleman's path, i require to set both parameters and looking for the middle. cause on this part, if i add mother(a,b) inside the ancestor, it require both different paths of answer to the result

Comment: I edited my answer to precise things about calling the predicate. If you need another predicate then directly specify it in the question by editing it please.

Comment: sorry mog, seems my previous ancestor's having some logical issue. i've made this country path to show out the problem much easier.

Comment: lol, sry for the careless mate, accidently left it over and forgot to change it. Done changing.

Comment: when i added 
country(germany,italy).
country(england,italy).
country(england,greece).
country(greece,france).
?-op(150,xfy,to). 
X to Y:-get_waypoints(X,Y,Waypoints),write(Waypoints),fail. 
funny things that it gave me is 
| ?- england to italy.
[] no
so i modified the 
get_waypoints(Start, End, [Waypoint|Result]) :-
    country(Start, End),
    !;country(Start, Waypoint),
    get_waypoints(Waypoint, End, Result).
which lead me to 
| ?- england to italy.
[_31242|_31243][france,bulgaria,germany,_31332|_31333][bulgaria,germany,_31422|_31423][greece,france,bulgaria,germany,_31602|_31603]no